# Extract multiple recurring text patterns

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string looking like this:

```
txt <- "|M  CHG  6  44  -1  48  -1  53  -1  63   1  64   1  65   1|"
```

The first digit (6) means that the pattern `\\s+\\d+\\s+[\\+-]?\\d+` recurs 6 times. Actually I'm only interested in the second (potentially signed) digit of this pattern. So I'm looking for a function or regular expression which gives me as a result

```
[1] "-1" "-1" "-1" "1" "1" "1"
```

I tried it with

```
gsub( "^\\|M\\s+CHG\\s+\\d+(\\s+\\d+\\s+([\\+-]?\\d+))+\\|$", replacement="\\2", x=txt, perl=TRUE )
```

as well as

```
str_replace_all( x, perl( "^\\|M\\s+CHG\\s+\\d+(\\s+\\d+\\s+([\\+-]?\\d+))+\\|$" ), "\\2" )
```

but in both cases I got only the last occurrence returned.

Comment: Do your strings all the start the same way, i.e. `|M  CHG  \\d`? With \\d being one or more digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to strip the beginning characters (I've done this with a `regex` but you might want to use `substr` or simillar. Then `matrix` into the required dimensions and return the column you want:

```
#  regex to strip superfluous characters
#  but `substring( txt , 10 )` would work just as well in this example
pat <- "^\\|M\\s+CHG\\s+\\d+\\s+(.*)\\|$"
x <- gsub( pat , "\\1" , txt )

#  Get result
matrix( unlist( strsplit( x , "\\s+" ) ) , ncol = 2 , byrow = 2 )[,2]
# [1] "-1" "-1" "-1" "1"  "1"  "1"
```

The intermediate `matrix` looks like this:

```
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "44" "-1"
#[2,] "48" "-1"
#[3,] "53" "-1"
#[4,] "63" "1" 
#[5,] "64" "1" 
#[6,] "65" "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a split on  with the end `|` removed. I'd only take what's after the 3rd element and the odd ones.

```
    var txt, txtArray, result;

txt = "|M  CHG  6  44  -1  48  -1  53  -1  63   1  64   1  65   1|";

// Remove the end '|';
txt = txt.slice(0, -1);

// Split on one or more space...
txtArray = txt.split(/\s+/);


// Grab the odd ones only after the third element...
result = txtArray.filter(function(n, i){
  return i > 3 && i % 2 === 0;
});

console.log( result );
```

Comment: I just realized this isn't a language I know. I've added an answer in Javascript should anyone need it!

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
txt <- "|M  CHG  6  44  -1  48  -1  53  -1  63   1  64   1  65   1|"    


#original
#txtsplit<-unlist(strsplit(txt, "\\s+"))
#n=as.numeric(txtsplit[3])
#o<-txtsplit[4+seq(from=1, by=2, length.out=n)]

#fixed
txtsplit<-unlist(strsplit(txt, "\\||\\s+"))
n=as.numeric(txtsplit[4])
o<-txtsplit[5+seq(from=1, by=2, length.out=n)]

#>o
[1] "-1" "-1" "-1" "1"  "1"  "1"
```

Comment: your example produces an "1|" as last element of the `strsplit` but still the most straight forward solution. I combined your solution with @SimonO101's `gsub`.

Comment: yes, that's right. I should have got rid of `|` too, glad it worked